# How to override active admin CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin, is there a way to override CSS used by the active admin theme?

For eg:- I have to change css of submit button which is disabled to cursor: wait; and make it unclickable.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You can't make a button unclickable with css, you need js to remove href or prevent the event. Also in order to change the cursor and look of the button when is clicked you can use js to change the class of the button.

Comment: Actually you can: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override any CSS property by overriding the CSS class or IDs in you own stylesheet with `!important` attribute if you do not have any access to the original stylesheet

For example, use

```
.submit-button {
    color: white !important;
}
```

to change the color of the submit button text.

Comment: I understand this is a very bad practice, because it overrides the replacement of CSS rules default behaviour. What you want are some rules that are either: more specific, or are defined later, so they're are replaced. If you put !important to all your rules, you won't be able to override anything. Try to *never* use !important

Comment: The author is using `Active Admin`, he can't create new rules like this and HAVE TO use `!important` to override the default rules. My answer is not a general answer but a "custom made" for the author, and he accepted it.

Comment: You can redefine Active Admin CSS rules just like any other CSS, by simply defining them later in the file. In the case of Rails, just after the @import clauses. What matters is the order in which the rules are created.

Answer (score 5):

just make a new file

```
app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss
```

and put your scss code there.

(Or just active_admin.css with css code)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to change the styles in Rails 4. Go to

> app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss

OR (depending upon where you have kept the file)

> vendor/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss

and add styles in there.

Answer (score 0):

I put my form classes in a container class to create a more specific reference. Like..

```
.form-container {
font-family: 'open-sans';
width: 420px;

  .text-field-class {
  input{border:none; border-bottom: 1px;}
  }

}
```

this is working so far... for the most part. Better than important. Though maybe using an ID would be the more appropriate way.